My application has started twice when i'm bringing up my container
I wrote a small c program(asks for user's name and prints 'welcome name') and a dockerfile to copy the program inside a container and execute it. I created the container and it exited after showing 'welcome name'. But after that whenever I'm starting the container, I can see 2 instances of my program running. I'm unable to understand why?
My small application(myapp.c) for proof of concept, it looks like this -
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char name[30] = {0};
printf("Enter your name: ");
gets(name);
printf("welcome ");
puts(name);
return 1;
} 

I've created a dockerfile to create an image which will run this application. My dockerfile looks like this -
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gcc
RUN mkdir /home/app/
#copy myapp.c in container
COPY . /home/app/
WORKDIR /home/app/
RUN ["gcc", "myapp.c", "-o", "myapp"]
CMD ./myapp 

After that I'm executing -
agangopadhyay@IN-RebhCTmbk5xO:~/docker/myapp$ docker build -t myappimage:1.0 .
agangopadhyay@IN-RebhCTmbk5xO:~/docker/myapp$ docker run -it --name mycontainer myappimage:1.0
Enter your name: Amiya
welcome Amiya           


Then the container exits as I think the main program exited.
agangopadhyay@IN-RebhCTmbk5xO:~/docker/myapp$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS       PORTS              NAMES
7e5b2a491353   myappimage:1.0   "/bin/sh -c ./myapp"   About an hour ago   Exited (137) 10 seconds ago mycontainer

But when I'm restarting the container using -
agangopadhyay@IN-RebhCTmbk5xO:~/docker/myapp$ docker start mycontainer
mycontainer
agangopadhyay@IN-RebhCTmbk5xO:~/docker/myapp$ docker exec -it mycontainer /bin/bash
root@7e5b2a491353:/home/app# ps -axu | grep myapp
root         1  0.1  0.0   2800  1168 pts/0    Ss+  14:04   0:00 /bin/sh -c ./myapp
root         7  0.0  0.0   2680  1072 pts/0    S+   14:04   0:00 ./myapp
root        17  0.0  0.0   3528  1684 pts/1    S+   14:04   0:00 grep --color=auto myapp

I can see 2 instances of myapp running. I wonder why?
Any pointer will be helpful.

Can you share more repeatable code? You can remove what's out of context, but it's much easier when you can copy what you have to replicate the issue. Also, please share the result of your docker command starting, then checking the instances running if possible

When you docker start the container, it doesn't have the original stdin attached.  IME you almost never need docker start: docker rm your old container and docker run it again (maybe with a --rm option so it cleans itself up).

docker start runs your CMD again. But now there's no TTY attached to the container, so it just hangs, waiting for input. In your ps output, you see the bash process, the process for your program and the grep process.

Your application is running once, the other process is a shell to launch your app. In this output:
root@7e5b2a491353:/home/app# ps -axu | grep myapp
root         1  0.1  0.0   2800  1168 pts/0    Ss+  14:04   0:00 /bin/sh -c ./myapp
root         7  0.0  0.0   2680  1072 pts/0    S+   14:04   0:00 ./myapp

Pid 1 is /bin/sh with the arguments -c and ./myapp. Your app is running as pid 7. If you want to eliminate the shell, you would switch to the exec syntax in the dockerfile:
CMD [ "./myapp" ]


you are right @BMitch.. PID 1 is for /bin/sh not myapp. Thank you for correcting me.
